# How to get just classes using requests

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-requests, typeclass

I want to just get all the classes on a website without any other information, but I don't know how to do it. Here is the code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://google.com'

r = requests.get(url).text

print(r)
```

Comment: the div classes like <div class="ctr-p" but automatic

Comment: the usual way is to use an html parser.